# Reversed S in Japanese transliteration

Tags: rōmaji

I recently found a strange spelling of a reversed S (Ƨ) on an old Japanese matchbox label (late 19th century), in the phrase "MANUFACTURED IN ƧEIRYUKWAN". At first I thought this was just a mistake in the graphics, or perhaps the Latin alphabet was not well known. However, I later found an example where the normal and reversed S occur side by side, in "OSAKANATUƧINSIYA ƧEIZU". This does look like the artist should've noticed. This made me wonder: is this some weird old-style form of transliteration, and what could the difference between those twop forms be? I don't speak Japanese unfortunately, so I couldn't come up with any guesses.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the matchbox? Seeing the Japanese text would help...

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to [this](http://arnon-reisman.blogspot.com/search/label/Seiryukwan)?

[image]

As far as I understand, 'reversed S' does not have any particular meaning, so I suppose this is probably a mere mistake, or maybe an intentional design element [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABBA#Official_logo). Other matchbox images from Seiryukwan (for example, [here](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/mz88/e/6a6ad5dd90f58378c4149796df29235a)) on the net do not have this "problem".

Comment: Yes. As I said, the side-by-side in the other example made me consider there might've been more to this.